# 再帰的にゆっくりファイルだけを削除するコマンド

Tags: linux, bash

あるディレクトリに対し再帰的にゆっくり削除をかけていきたいと思っています。

```
find . -exec sleep 1 \; -delete
```

このコマンドでほぼ満たされるのですが、ディレクトリは削除せずに残しておきたいのです。
どのようにするとできそうでしょうか？よろしくお願いします。

Comment: `find . \! -type d -exec sleep 1 \; -delete` でどうでしょうか。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
find . ! -type d -exec sleep 1 \; -delete
```

これでいかがでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

別解です。
rm コマンドは、ディレクトリを消さないので、こういう書き方もあります。

```
find . -exec echo {} \; | while read f; do sleep 1; rm $f; done
```

利点: do に複数コマンドを書けるのでログ出力つけたくなった時に便利です。
ひとつのファイル/リンクを消すための待ち時間を揃えるには、Shirone さんの回答にある「! -type d」を使うのが良いです。

Comment: `find . -exec echo {} \;` ではファイル一つごとに echo コマンドの起動がかかり、無駄に負荷がかかります。`find . -print` で充分で負荷も少ないです。

Comment: 確かにそっちのほうが良い。それに分かりやすいですね。